# Return a value from loop in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, baobab

I need to find node by id in the tree. For that i am going down with help of two nested loops. But returned undefined.

```
function searchInTreeById(node, matchingId) {
    var res;
    if (node.select('id').get() == matchingId) {
        res = node.get();
        return res
    } else {
        if (node.exists('childObjects')) {
            node.select('childObjects').map(function (cursor, i) {
                cursor.select('children').map(function (cursorChild, j) {

                    if (cursorChild.select('id').get() === matchingId) {
                        // console.log(cursorChild.get()) //this console.log is execute
                        res = cursorChild.get();
                        return res;
                    } else {
                        // console.log(cursorChild.get())
                        searchInTreeById(cursorChild, matchingId)
                    }
                })
            })
        } else {
            res = node;
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: Ignoring result of `searchInTreeById` look very suspicions (not sure what "baobab" is, so maybe it is ok in that whatever it is)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov if i set res= searchInTreeById(cursorChild, matchingId), then func return the last visited node...

Comment: Side note: `map` is usually wrong way to perform search - most likely there is another function (similar to `Array.find`) that allows to stop iteration in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the match is not immediately found, you call recursively the function which should eventually return the result. But it does not.

```
searchInTreeById(cursorChild, matchingId);
```

However, using *map* will apply the check/function to every child, but the result is lost anyway, in this case. The *map* function applies the function given in parameters to the array elements, and return the new value for each element - a new array. Depending how quickly the item is found, a copy of the tree is built in memory (a traditional recursive function keeps only the path of elements up to a node).

So you could assign the map result to an array, which each element is set to *null* if that particular child didn't have a match, or the *node* if found. Then you check all elements of that created array, and return either *null* or *node* if found (then, the caller fills the array at that level etc...).

You could also use a global variable

```
var found = null;
```

only set when there is a match (nothing done otherwise). Since it seems a *map* is not breakable, the children at that level will be checked anyway. But, the difference is that before calling recursively the function again, you check the global variable, and call *only* if *found* is still null.

But maybe *map* could be avoided all together?

Instead of using *map*, gather the children in an array and iterate over that array, calling recursively the function, and return immediately the node matching.

Suggested code (not tested)

```
function searchInTreeById(node, matchingId) {
    if (node.select('id').get() == matchingId) {
        return node.get();
    }
    if (node.exists('childObjects')) {
         var list = node.select('childObjects');
         for(var i=0 ; i<list.length ; i++) {
             var res = searchInTreeById(list[i], matchingId);
             if (res) return res;
         }
     }
     return null;
}
```

Disclaimer: *baobab* first timer. (I read [this](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab) though)

Comment: thank you so much!!!! i modified this code a little bit, and it's work how it shoulld be!

Comment: So what did you change, use a global var? get the map result in an array? Iterate over the children?

Comment: iterate over the childrens and change parts, connected with baobab? like this:
 var list = parentNode.select('childObjects').get();